# django-nginx-gunicorn - not working

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to setup django with nginx and gunicorn by these tutorials http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/ and http://honza.ca/2011/05/deploying-django-with-nginx-and-gunicorn

Setup:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages qlimp
cd qlimp
source bin/activate
pip install gunicorn django
django-admin.py startproject qlimp
cd qlimp
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Gunicorn setup is same as here http://senko.net/en/django-nginx-gunicorn/

changes made (run.sh):

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/qlimp.log
USER=nirmal
GROUP=nirmal
cd /home/nirmal/qlimp/qlimp
```

Upstart is also the same as the tutorial in above link

changes made:

```
exec /home/nirmal/qlimp/qlimp/run.sh
```

Nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name qlimp.com;

    access_log /home/nirmal/qlimp/log/access.log;
    error_log /home/nirmal/qlimp/log/error.log;

    location /static {
         root /home/nirmal/qlimp/qlimp;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
```

}

Then I restarted nginx and run the gunicorn server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
(qlimp) cd qlimp/qlimp
(qlimp) gunicorn_django -D -c run.sh
```

When I run the gunicorn server, I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to read config file: run.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nirmal/qlimp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line  65, in load_config
execfile(opts.config, cfg, cfg)
 File "run.sh", line 3
   LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/qlimp.log
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone guide me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Run.sh obviosly not a config file for gunicorn. You need to run run.sh itself.

Comment: Could you give me the clear setup and changes bcoz I'm new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Try /etc/gunicorn.d instead of your own script for gunicorn

Answer (score 0):

Try /etc/gunicorn.d instead of your own sh file

Comment: Could you give a sample setup for my project? Btw thanks for the help

Comment: sorry im a bit late. But if you have gunicor installed systemwide just start the gunicorn instance with /etc/gunicorn.d

Answer (score 0):

I Configure Django App with Gunicorn and Nginx on EC2

nano /etc/init/site1.conf

```
description "site1 web server"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /home/scripts/gunicorn_runserver.sh
```

and in gunicorn_runserver.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
  set -e
  LOGFILE=/var/log/nginx/site1.log
  NUM_WORKERS=10
  # user/group to run as
  USER=www-data
  GROUP=adm
  cd /home/projects/project_name/
  #  source ../../bin/activate
  exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=error \
    --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

Nginx conf

```
upstream app_server_hana {
server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

location  / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass http://app_server_site1;
          break;
  }
}
```

Finally

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
service site1 start
```

Comment: From what I understand, exposing port 8000 defeats the purpose of nginx and gunicorn. All communication should be done via port 80 with nginx which communicates with the unix socket that gunicorn creates for django. Leaving 8000 directly open introduces vulnerabilities.